# technical question concerning uncountabilty of nouns

Tags: verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

I would like to know this once and for all if it is allowed to turn an uncountable noun into plural when two types of a particular noun are mentioned.

for example, "the side and tip resistance of piles are calculated."
with regard to the uncountability of 'resistance' as a noun, it does not sound right to use it as singular when two types of resistance (tip and side) are presented. 
Plus, this sentence can be paraphrased in many ways to get the point across, but what about his particular instance?

Comment: *Resistance* governs both *side* and *tip*, so the sentence means "side resistance and tip resistance". In that case the subject is a compound conjunction and thus plural, regardless of the countability of *resistance*. You may say *side and tip resistances*, in which case the modifier is compound.

Comment: @deadrat thank you. so it would still be true if I say 'Tip and side post-groutings', right? using post-grouting in plurality.

Comment: It's not right as a plural. The head of the NP is the singular "resistance", so the verb should also be the singular "is". "Side and tip" are compound modifiers of "resistance" and have no bearing on the number of the phrase.

Comment: @BillJ Maybe, but not if it's structured like this: "The side  [resistance] and tip resistance are ..."

Comment: I assume that *post-grouting* is a (countable) thing, and that there are two types: *tip post-grouting* and *side post-grouting*. If so, the plural is appropriate. If *tip and post* is one thing, like the drink gin and tonic, then the singular is appropriate. If the compound is really grouting for tip posts and side posts, then use *tip- and side-post groutings* if you consider *grouting* countable (e.g., two separate jobs) or *tip- and side-post grouting* if you consider *grouting* as noncountable, collective term.

Comment: The side and tip resistance values are calculated.  I don't know where to put "of piles" because this is technical jargon I'm not familiar with.

Comment: 'I would like to know this once and for all if it is allowed to turn an uncountable noun into plural when two types of a particular noun are mentioned.' assumes that English is well-behaved. It's not.